# Clustering of SVG Elements in d3.js yields unexpected results

Tags: svg, coffeescript, d3.js

So I'm trying to do some map marker clustering for a project that uses d3.js, polymaps and Coffeescript.

I compute the clusters based on the underlying data, and then pass the clustered array into d3 as .data(clusters)

The placement of the clusters seems to be ok. The clustering on the initial zoom level seems to be ok, and based on my knowledge is 100% accurate. When I change zoom levels, everything seems ok at first glance, but when I hover over the circles, the description doesn't seem to match up with where they are, and where the routes were before, doesn't seem to match where they are now.

I prepared an example of this at http://bl.ocks.org/3161013 that includes the full code.

I see two major points of failure for this: Clustering, and updating the SVG.

The code for clustering is fairly simple, and based on that from [Mark Tuupola](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps), but in coffeescript instead of php.

```
  cluster: (elements, distance) ->
    currentElements = elements.slice(0)
    pixelDistance = @pixelDistance()
    distLat = distance * pixelDistance.lat
    distLon = distance * pixelDistance.lon 

    clustered = []
    while currentElements.length > 0
      stop = currentElements.shift()

      cluster = []
      cluster.push stop

      i = 0
      while i < currentElements.length
        if Math.abs(currentElements[i].lat - stop.lat) < distLat and Math.abs(currentElements[i].lon - stop.lon) < distLon
          aStop = currentElements.splice i,1
          cluster.push aStop[0]
          i--
        i++
      clustered.push cluster  
    clustered
```

The code for SVG updates seems like fairly straight forward d3 code. When ever the map is moved, this update method gets called. If the zoom has changed, or the pre-clustered data has changed, we re-cluster, and layout, otherwise we just translate the existing points.

```
  update: ->
    if not @stops
      @stops = []

    if not @prevNumStops
      @prevNumStops = 0

    if not @prevZoom
      @prevZoom = 0


    if @zoomLevel() != @prevZoom or @prevNumStops != @stops.length
      @prevZoom = @zoomLevel()
      @prevNumStops = @stops.length 

      start = new Date()
      @clusters = @cluster(@stops,10)
      console.log @clusters
      console.log "clustering: " + ((new Date()) - start)

      start = new Date()
      marker = @selector.selectAll("g").data(@clusters)
      marker.enter().append("g")
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "stop no-tip")
      marker.exit().remove()
      @selector.selectAll("g").selectAll("circle")
      .attr('r', (cluster) -> if cluster.length > 1 then 5 else 3.5)
      .attr("text", (cluster) -> "<ul>" + ((("<li>" + route + "</li>") for route in stop.routes).join("") for stop in cluster).join("") + "</ul>")

    @selector.selectAll("g").attr("transform", (cluster) => 
      @transform cluster[0]
    )
```

I feel like there's probably something easy I'm missing here, but I'm still fairly new to d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'circle' elements inside the existing markers are not updated when the data changes (d3 uses indices per default to figure out whether new elements are added (enter), removed (exit) or updated (default)). This causes the text to be the old text from the previous zoom level for all elements that already existed on that zoom level.

It should work with the following code:

```
marker = @selector.selectAll("g").data(@clusters)

# update existing 'g' elements
marker.select('circle')
.attr('r', your_cluster_size_function)
.attr("text", your_text_function)


# add new 'g' elements
marker.enter().append("g")
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "stop no-tip")
.attr('r', your_cluster_size_function)
.attr("text", your_text_function)

# remove 'g' elements if there are too many
marker.exit().remove()
```